# Query::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp:

Tags: regex

I am using the following regular expression `^AI-(?:(?!IPM)(?!RISK).)*-d+$` to search at mysql table for all expressions starting with AI- and then containing neither IPM nor RISK. When I run it, I get the following error:

> Query::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp:

I don't know how to convert to a valid expression.

Comment: Wouldn't `/^AI-(?!(IPM|RISK).+?)-d+$/` suffice?

Comment: Just replace the non capture group with a **capture** group: `^AI-((?!IPM)(?!RISK).)*-d+$`

Comment: @shaedrich: Your regex matches `AI-blahIPMblah-123` for example, but it shouldn't.

Comment: What should it match instead? The thread owner didn't specify an expected result.

Comment: @shaedrich: It's well explain in question: `all expressions starting with AI- and then containing neither IPM nor RISK`

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` uses `POSIX` regexes which don't support the use of `(?:..)` as a grouping prefix.

[POSIX Regex](http://MySQL%20uses%20POSIX%20regexes%20which%20don%27t%20support%20the%20use%20of%20(?:..)%20as%20a%20grouping%20prefix.%20%20https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_05)

Your Regex will probably work in Notepad++ etc. but not MySQL.

[RegexBuddy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

You can test a POSIX Regex online here: http://www.rexv.org/

[image]